# VBA: Displaying Row Numbers Completed in Run Time

Tags: vba

I couldn't observe the number of rows completed during run time. Hence I was thinking why not just come out few line of codes to display the number of rows completed in run time.

Follow are my implementation:

```
Dim ownCntrl As Control
Set ownCntrl = UserForm1.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1")
With ownCntrl
    .Name = "RowNoTextBox"
    .Value = "test"
    .Width = 150
    .Height = 25
    .Top = 10
    .Left = 10
    .ZOrder (0)
End With
UserForm1.Show
```

Following are my queries:

1)Beside TextBox Object, is there any other Object like label in Java to display information in VBA?

2)Without Created a UserForm called "UserForm1" initially, can I create the TextBox Object or other suitable Object Directly during run time? Cause, without called the UserForm1.Show function, the TextBox Object won't display

3)How can I remain the UserForm or TextBox to display during run time without users' interaction to close it to proceed?

I'm just start to learn VBA. Appreciate you guys' suggestions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your goal to display progress information?? Search for 'progress bar' in google or here in SO where I have seen few possibilities... Which information do you want to display- only some text with numbers?

Comment: Third Problem is solved by calling UserForm1.Show(0)

Comment: Hi, KazJaw. Nice to see you around. I just want to display the number of rows completed during runtime in a textbox or label. That's all

Comment: Hi, KazJaw. I think progress information is a good idea. I'm looking at it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm sorry not to answering your question as you expect but I give you a tip which I prefer. Use within your code `Application.StatusBar = "Current progres- Row No.:" & rowNum` to show the progress during runtime in statusbar in excel application. Keep in mind that at the end of your subroutine you have to us this line `Application.StatusBar = False`.

Comment: Answering your first question, yes, there is `Label` control available for you.

Comment: Hi, KazJaw. I really appreciate your suggestion. You already gave what I want to have. Thanks a lot, sincerely

Comment: You're welcome... I added this suggestion as answer, too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to some additional information placed in comments the simplest idea to keep information about progress of your subroutine is to use Excel status bar. Therefore we put within our subroutine something like this:

```
Application.StatusBar = "Current progress- Row No.: " & rowNum
```

where `rowNum` is a variable (loop variable) representing current row.
Which is important- you need to return standard status bar behaviour calling this line before end of your procedure:

```
Application.StatusBar = False
```